# Top border Colour at top of sub menu

Tags: css, border

I am trying to change the colour of the top border on my sub menu drop down list from black to beige. However the new border colour I have added sits on top of the existing black border! I have used the following:

```
 .eltd-menu-inner {
  border-top: 3px solid  #a88f4b;
  }
```

How do I target the existing black border?

http://boxofficeboxing.co.uk/

Thanks in advance.
Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be worked.

```
.eltd-drop-down .eltd-menu-second .eltd-menu-inner>ul, li.eltd-menu-narrow .eltd-menu-second .eltd-menu-inner ul { border-top: 3px solid #a88f4b; }
```

Comment: @Dee, Try this and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @Dee, It's my pleasure :)

Comment: Well there is one small thing...is there a way I can use my boxing glove avatar for people who are not users who leave a message on my blog as opposed to the mystery man avatar? http://boxofficeboxing.co.uk/news/tyson-fury-is-definately-finished/